# Given $f(x,y,z)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ show that $d^2f\geq0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Given $f(x,y,z)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ show that $d^2f\geq0$

After calculations I get

$$f_{xx}=\frac{y^2+z^2}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^\frac{3}{2}}$$
$$f_{yy}=\frac{x^2+z^2}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^\frac{3}{2}}$$
$$f_{zz}=\frac{y^2+x^2}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^\frac{3}{2}}$$
$$f_{xy}=\frac{-xy}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$
$$f_{xz}=\frac{-xz}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$
$$f_{yz}=\frac{-yz}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$

So $$d^2f=\frac{y^2+z^2}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^\frac{3}{2}}dx^2+\frac{x^2+z^2}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^\frac{3}{2}}dy^2+\frac{y^2+x^2}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^\frac{3}{2}}dz^2-2\frac{-xy}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}dxdy-2\frac{-xz}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}dxdz-2\frac{-yz}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}dydz$$

How arrive to a conclusion?

Answer (score 1):

The denominator is the same and it's positive (unless $x=y=z=0$), so $$(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac32}d^2f=(y^2+z^2)dx^2+(x^2+z^2)dy^2+(y^2+x^2)dz^2+2xydxdy+2xzdxdz+2yzdydz$$
By expanding the parentheses on the right hand side and reordering the terms you get $$(y^2dx^2+2xydxdy+x^2dy^2)+(z^2dx^2+2xzdxdz+x^2dz^2)+(y^2dz^2+2yzdydz+z^2dy^2)=\\(ydx+xdy)^2+(zdx+xdz)^2+(ydz+zdy)^2$$
That is a sum of squares, so it is always non-negative.